# ion-card full height in ion-slide

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic3

I am trying to make an ion-card responsive within an ion-slide. The responsive grid works in the card, but when I add the ion-slides and ion-slide element, it doesn't. Do you have an idea what I am missing? I think it could have something to do with the not inherited height from the slide, but I cant figure it out how to do it. Putting the same css code of ion-card in ion-slide or ion-slides doesn help.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Harun

HTML:

```
 <ion-slides>
<ion-slide>
  <ion-card>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row class="row1">
          <ion-col>
            ROW 1
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row class="row2">
          <ion-col>
            ROW 2
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-card>
</ion-slide>
```

CSS:

```
  ion-grid {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }

  ion-card {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    border: 3px solid green;
  }

  .row1 {
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    border: 3px solid orange;
  }

  .row2 {
    height: 100%;
    flex: 2;
    border: 3px solid red;
  }
```